# what is the best approach to apply multiple transformations to an apache RDD?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I have huge files containing a lot or ndline json data on it. Using airflow I am trying to process those files in an EMR cluster to get a new set of files. Should I use multiple steps inside the EMR or make all the procesing in one pyspark  script and send only one step tho the EMR?

Here it is an example:

### data file:

```
{"key": {"nested_key": "value"}}
{"key": {"nested_key": "value2"}}
```

### result file:

```
{"nested_key": "value", "nested_hashed": hashed_value}
{"nested_key": "value2",  "nested_hashed": hashed_value2}
```

### pyspark code

```
def flatenize(data):
     data = json.loads(data)
     return json.dumps(data['key'])

def hash_data(data):
     data = json.loads(data)
     data['nested_hashed'] = hash(data['nested_key'])
     return json.dumps(data)

def main()
    sparkccontext = pyspark.SparkContext(master='local[4]', appName='test')
    input = args.input_files
    output = args.output_files

    rdd = sparkccontext.textFile(input)
    flatrdd = rdd.map(flatenize)
    output_rdd = flatrdd.map(hash_data)
    output_rdd.saveAsTextFile(output)
```

will be better to run this 2 maps in 2 separate scripts?

Comment: On the contrary, I'd typically inline those functions in a single chain of spark method calls. And if in "separate scripts" you also include this initializing of the spark context, then clearly the answer is no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the best approach is to chain all the operations like this:

```
output_rdd = flatrdd.map(flatenize).map(hash_data)
```